# Ajax php call and setInterval() not running together

Tags: setinterval

Basically my code contains two modules. One to update the data in an ajax call and another module loads the response from an external php to a  element. I am trying to implement a chat mechanism. Where user texts data and gets updated chat history without loading the page

The submit ajaxsubmit.php wont work properly with the load fetch-conversation.php loading chat data. This results in execution of alert("Please Fill All Fields")

```js
function auto_refresh()
{
if(writing==false){$('#message-container').load(<?php echo "'fetch-conversation.php?id=$id'"?>);}
}


setInterval('auto_refresh()', 1000);
```

```html
<script>
var writing=false;
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
writing=true;
var content = $("#content").val();
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
var dataString = 'content='+ content ;

if(content=='')
{
alert("Please Fill All Fields");
}
else
{
// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(result){
alert(result);
writing=false;
}
});
}
return false;
});


});
</script>
```

Comment: Great, but you haven't said what's wrong or asked a question.

Comment: Well the question was in the title. It was my bad not to elaborate the question though. The both said functionality dont work in the presence of another. The submit ajaxsubmit.php wont work properly  with the load fetch-conversation.php loading chat data. This results in execution of 

alert("Please Fill All Fields");

Comment: Sir, can you help me or suggest something? :/ i am in a fix